# How do I build a SAML login link dynamically?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I want a link on my login page that says "Log in with [identity provider]".  For ssocircle, apparently the login link is

```
https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/idpssoinit?metaAlias=%2Fpublicidp
```

But this link isn't located anywhere in the XML used to configure it.  The IdP XML contains the following:

```
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/publicidp"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/publicidp"/>
<SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOSoap/metaAlias/publicidp"/>
```

Is it not possible to build the URL from these? Do I need to add a configuration for every IdP that includes asking for the login URL as well as the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the URL that you call on the IDP is out of scope for SAML.

SAML only specify that it is possible for the IDP to start the authentication itself, not what triggers it to start. This is why it is not present in metadata

Comment: What are the URLs in the <SingleSignOnService> attributes for?

Comment: These tell the IDP where to send the assertion ones the user is autehtnicated

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you describe you should use Service Provider initiated SSO. In that case the URL that will be used to send the AuthnRequest to is defined in the metadata XML that you mentioned.

But you end up with a logic in your own application which must generate the correct  AuthnRequest. But that URL is under your control ...

Image from the spec describes the SP initiated flow:

[image]

Comment: Does that result in you being redirected to the idp to log in?

Comment: Yes. I have added an image from spec which describes the sp initiated flow.